# How to go another level deeper in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I've got an array which has two levels (sorry if that's the wrong terminology) and I can access the first level but I want to go another level down.

Could someone point me in the right direction so I can access that data and output it?

Fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/ep2Lqzum/

```
var myStringArray = [
    ["a", "b", "c"],
  ["d", "e", "f"]
];

var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  console.log(myStringArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: try this `myStringArray[i][0])` it would in your case select `a` and `d`

Comment: The "level" is called a `dimension`.  You have a *2-dimensional array* - it can be n-dimensional.

Comment: Use a second for loop to iterate through the deeper level of the array

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Answer (score -1):

Use another iteration inside the outer loop.

Here I use `.foreach()` but you can use any kind of loops you want.

Now you can access the deeper level of the array.

```js
let myStringArray = [["a", "b", "c"],["d", "e", "f"]]
myStringArray.forEach(array => {
  console.log(array)
  array.forEach(character => {
    console.log(character)
  })
})
```